# C# HttpListener Cookies expiring after session even though expiration time set

Tags: c#, cookies, httplistener

I have an `HttpListener` class for handling logins to a page, and can successfully set the cookie, but the cookie is expiring at the end of the session (using cookie extension in Chrome, shows cookie is a session cookie).  Here is the code snippet:

```
CookieCollection ccol = new CookieCollection();    
Cookie loginCookie = new Cookie();

loginCookie.Name = "login";
loginCookie.Value = "loggedin";
loginCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);
ccol.Add(loginCookie);
context.Response.Cookies = ccol;
```

As long as I am in the same session I can access the cookie without issue.

Comment: could you post a network trace of the headers that your login page is returning to the client? Looking at the headers will make it easier to diagnose what's going on.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, the cookie collection (`Cookies`) property is read only (at least when using the ASP.NET `Response.Cookies` property).

It's been a while since I used the `HttpListener`, so do you know if the Cookies collection is null prior to assigning your own cookie collection? If not, can you try simply adding a cookie rather than a cookie collection?

**Edit:**

I built a test webserver using `HttpListener` and this is what I found.
When you set a cookie the http header looks like this:

> Set-Cookie: username=shiv

whereas it should really be something like:

> Set-Cookie: username=shiv;
>   expires=Thu, 27-Jan-2011 00:45:41 GMT;
>   path=/

So for the moment it looks like a bug? I'll dig deeper and let you know...

**Edit 2:**

Ok, the `Expiration` time of cookies needs to be set as GMT time. ASP.NET takes care of this for you, but in this case you'll have to use the proper format yourself.

Manually setting the Http Header works as expected:

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", 
"username=shiv; expires=Thu, 27-Jan-2011 00:45:41 GMT; path=/");
```

where `context` is `HttpListenerContext`.

This seems to be the only way to set a (non session) cookie using the `HttpListener`. You can use this `DateTime` format string to format the date correctly if you go down the route I suggested:

```
var cookieDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60d).ToString("dddd, dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was able to expand upon it and solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I can't believe they released cookie code that doesn't really work as expected.  I wish they had called the method SetSessionCookie() so it would be obvious.  I fought with this for way too long, thinking I must have done something wrong, before I found out that the set cookie feature in HttpListener is broken.  BTW: You can't include GMT in the format string for the date unless you escape the M.  Otherwise it gets turned into the month.

Comment: There are some mismatches in the `ToString` format and the date format you wanted (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Also as @Steve Hiner has said the `M` in `GMT` gets translated.  The `d` in `AddMinutes` is also surplus. For the correct string format see the answer by @Mike J.  (Although good work for finding the source of the issue. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by doing the following:

```
string cookieDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60).ToString("ddd, dd-MMM-yyyy H:mm:ss");

context.Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", "cookieName=cookieValue;Path=/;Expires=" + cookieDate + " GMT");
```